# CakePHP plus sign in named parameter decode as space

Tags: cakephp, named

This is problem with value of named parameter when the value contain character `+` (plus).

The url is http://localhost/kidwatcher/messages/sentbox/number:+6581235251237

When I try to `var_dump` the named paramater (which in this case is `number`), character `+` becomes a space.

```
string(14) " 6581235251237"
```

Character `+` is `%2B`, the result is same when I change the url:

```
http://localhost/kidwatcher/messages/sentbox/number:%2B6581235251237

string(14) " 6581235251237"
```

But when I use url query string, it works.

```
http://localhost/kidwatcher/messages/sentbox?number=%2B6581235251237

string(14) "+6581235251237"
```

What's wrong with named parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, now i have solution for this problem.

In folder app/webroot

Edit .htaccess to

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L,B]
</IfModule>
```